# onPostExecute getResources().getString NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, getstring

When I run below code in the onPostExecute, it gives me an exception: `java.lang.NullPointerException`

```
getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_sth);
getBaseContext().getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_sth);
```

`R.string.lbl_sth` is definitely correct. If I run above two lines in `onCreate`, both lines work as expected.

Comment: did you solved it? I'm facing the same problem

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `getBaseContext()` in your `AsyncTask`... pass your `Activity` as a context to the `AsyncTask` instead. Then call `getResources().getString(...)` on the `Activity` directly.

Comment: NOT work. Inside the onPostExecute I call a UI's method, in that method I try to getString(R.string.lbl_sth). But no luck with any solution. Activity already there, still java.lang.NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the Strings from the Resources in the constructor of the AsyncTask:

```
public MyAsyncTask(String lblString) {
    this.lblString = lblString; 
}
```

you would construct and execute your task like this from an Activity/Fragment:

```
new MyAsyncTask(getString(R.string.lbl_sth)).execute();
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to use getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_sth);

Comment: It is not possible to 'getActivity' inside AsyncTask.